# Update order with basket xml

Tags: shopify, opayo

I'm trying to update a sagepay order's basket xml via shopify's create order webhook.

However, I cannot find any reference in the sagepay integration docs on an API endpoint for updating an orders basket xml. A lot of different examples of how to format the XML but nothing specific on where it should be sent.

For those who don't know/use shopify, I do not have access to the sagepay form but the webhook has full access to the transaction and order details itself.

Thanks for any help given!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BasketXML forms part of the transaction post. As soon as the transaction post is submitted to Sage Pay with basket details the basket cannot be subsequently amended with Sage Pay for that transaction.